# Difference in Postgres SQL query result in Shell execution vs Entity Framework SqlRaw

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have following query, which when executed from postgres Shell gets me correct meetings and includes participants per each meeting

```
SELECT id, subject, organizer, starttime, endtime, tmp.participants
from "Meetings" m
         left join lateral (
    select jsonb_agg(row_to_json(tp)) as participants
    from (select p.name, p.title
          from "Meetings_Participants" mp
                   inner join "Participants" p on mp."ParticipantId" = p.id
          where mp."MeetingId" = m.id
         ) tp
    ) tmp on true
WHERE starttime::date <= NOW()::date
  and endtime::date >= NOW()::date;
```

when I run this equivalent in Entity Framework I do get correct meetings but participants list is always Null ???

```
return db.Meetings.FromSqlRaw<Meeting>(
        "SELECT id, subject, organizer, starttime, endtime, tmp.participants " +
        "from \"Meetings\" m " +
                 "left join lateral (" +
            "select jsonb_agg(row_to_json(tp)) as participants " +
            "from (select p.name, p.title " +
                  "from \"Meetings_Participants\" mp " +
                           "inner join \"Participants\" p on mp.\"ParticipantId\" = p.id " +
                  "where mp.\"MeetingId\" = m.id " +
                 ") tp" +
            ") tmp on true " +
        "WHERE starttime::date <= NOW()::date "+
          "and endtime::date >= NOW()::date"
        ).ToList<Meeting>();
```

Comment: what happens if you execute the query directly through the EF connection?

Comment: @satnhak Im very new to EF, what do you mean ? how can i execute it directly ? I got this code by following tutorials so I am not very familiar with anything else

Comment: something like `var con = db.Database.GetDbConnection()` will give you the connection that EF uses, then this should help. my guess is that those columns don't map onto your `Mapping` DTO.

Comment: if you want to do this kind of thing then I recommend looking at `Dapper`, it's much better for raw queries, EF really isn't meant for that sort of thing. https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper